# class path resource [static/pixel.png] cannot be opened because it does not exist (Heroku)

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, jhipster, pixel

Im developing a spring boot application using Jhipster, and Im trying to add pixel to email.
The pixel image saved on resources/static folder.
My pixel link:

```
    @GetMapping("/email-status/OPENED/{customer}")
    @Timed
    public void mailOpened(@PathVariable String customer, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        //code...

        InputStream in = new ClassPathResource("/static/pixel.png").getInputStream();

        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE);
        IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    }
```

[The static folder explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98DHr.png)

When i call the api from the browser with localhost:8080/api/email-status/OPENED/...
the pixel image is displayed.

But when I call from my **Domain** https://app.mydomain.com/api/email-status/OPENED/123

(I'm using **Heroku** for hosting)
I get this error

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [static/pixel.png] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Anyone know why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the localhost uses the generated classes where the domain uses the jar. In the latter case the image is inside the jar and that is why cannot be found.

As the document states for [ClassPathResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html):

> Supports resolution as java.io.File if the class path resource resides
> in the file system, **but not for resources in a JAR**

Maybe you should consider using

```
YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/static/pixel.png")
```

A very useful link about using resources is the ["How to Use Icons"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)

Answer (score 0):

In case you deployed your app on a webserver in order to access it from your domain, it could only access the image if it is also stored on the same server.

In that case you'd have to copy the image in the appropriate folder on your server.

Answer (score 0):

So I did not find any answer, The image is exists in the files, but yet couldn't use any Local path resource solution ..

I have decided to host the image and use the link instead of static image, This is my **working solution**

```
InputStream in = new URL("https://some-host/12345/pixel.png").openStream();
response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE);
IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
```

And one more thing that was must for me is also, the img tag should contain all those params

```
<img src="image_url(the pixel image)" alt="Logo" title="Logo" style="display:block" width="1" height="1" />
```